# HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier scope

Tags: java, scala, ssl, jvm

Periodically there is a problem when remote server certificate is buggy and has mismatch in certificate CN vs domain name and I cannot influence this. To come over this problem there is a solution - create and set dummy hostname verifier (scala syntax in example):

```
val hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
  def verify(s: String, sslSession: SSLSession) = true
}
```

In case where I have access to real connection I can set this verifier per connection basis:

```
https_connection.setHostnameVerifier(hv)
```

But in case where I can't control connection directly, like using wsimport generated SOAP wrapper, I do:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv)
```

And set it for class.

Question: if I have tomcat webapp which uses classes connecting with HTTPS and one of them set's default verifier using static method, which is the scope this change affects?

Alternative question: how to set hostname verifier in wsimport generated SOAP webservices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question might be a bit unprofessional but it took me some time to grasp, maybe will save somebody's time.

> Question: if I have tomcat webapp which uses classes connecting with
>   HTTPS and one of them set's default verifier using static method,
>   which is the scope this change affects?

I did small test where in a simple servlet in one request I set up `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv)` and in subsequest I read `getHostnameVerifier` from the new HttpsURLConnection object. Of course it is the same I set in first request, how could it be in other way. So scope is at least the scope of tomcat webapp.

---

> Alternative question: how to set hostname verifier in wsimport generated SOAP webservices?

Use `JAXWSProperties.HOSTNAME_VERIFIER`:

```
val ws = (new MyJAXWSWebService()).getMyJAXWSWebServiceSoap
val context = ws.asInstanceOf[BindingProvider].getRequestContext

// their certificate doesn't match domain!
context.put(JAXWSProperties.HOSTNAME_VERIFIER, new HostnameVerifier() {
  def verify(s: String, sslSession: SSLSession) = true
})
```